# Device.BeginInvokeOnThread() block the await operator.Is there any other way to update the UI in xamarin forms

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, uwp, visual-studio-2017

I am working on xamarin forms Cross platform.
I have a function createform in which i am calling the buildform function.My build form function is used to generate the UI.
 I am callling my create form inside the constructor.

```
public FormsPage()
{
    json = new JsonSerialize();

    //Task.createForm("form5");
    Task.Run(() => createForm("form5")).Wait();
}

public async void createForm(string path)
{
    this.path = path;
    definition =json.parseJson(path);

    formdata = await json.parseJsonFormData(path);



    //var x = (bool)formdata["Form"][1]["Section_OtherInfo"]["IsNop"];
    // buildForm();

    Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(buildForm);
}
```

If i am not using Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(buildForm) then it is throwing an exception for UWP.And If i am using Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(buildForm) then it is blocking the await operator.

The prototype of my BUildForm function is:

```
public void  buildForm()
{
    try
    {
        JToken y = formdata["Form"];
        if (!(y.HasValues))
        {
            CreateJson();
        }
        data.Clear();
        var section = new StackLayout
        {
            BackgroundColor = Color.White,
            HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand
        };
        var sectionLayout = new StackLayout
        {
            Padding = 10,
            BackgroundColor = Color.White,
            HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand
        };

        var sectionheader = new StackLayout
        {
            BackgroundColor = Color.FromHex("#7635EB"),
            HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand
        };

        var mainLayout = new StackLayout
        {
            Padding = 10,
            BackgroundColor = Color.FromHex("#DCDCDC")

        };
        var horizontalLayoutNaNop = new StackLayout
        {
            Orientation = StackOrientation.Horizontal,
            BackgroundColor = Color.White
        };

        var horizontalLayout = new StackLayout
        {
            Orientation = StackOrientation.Horizontal,
            BackgroundColor = Color.White
        };

        this.Title = definition.Title;



        //foreach (var sc in definition.Section)
        for (var i = 0; i < definition.Section.Count; i++)
        {

            section = new StackLayout
            {
                BackgroundColor = Color.White,
                HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand
            };
            sectionheader = new StackLayout
            {
                BackgroundColor = Color.FromHex("#7635EB"),
                HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand
            };
            horizontalLayout = new StackLayout
            {
                Orientation = StackOrientation.Horizontal,
                BackgroundColor = Color.White
            };
            sectionLayout = new StackLayout
            {
                Padding = 10,
                BackgroundColor = Color.White,
                HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand
            };
            if (definition.Section[i].SectionTitle != string.Empty)
            {


                var title = new Label
                {
                    Text = definition.Section[i].SectionTitle,
                    HorizontalTextAlignment = TextAlignment.Start,
                    TextColor = Color.White,
                    FontSize = 20,
                    FontAttributes = FontAttributes.Bold,
                    Margin = new Thickness(10, 5, 5, 5)

                };


                sectionheader.Children.Add(title);
                section.Children.Add(sectionheader);
            }
            if (definition.Section[i].IsNa || definition.Section[i].IsNop)
            {
                horizontalLayoutNaNop = new StackLayout
                {
                    Orientation = StackOrientation.Horizontal,
                    BackgroundColor = Color.White
                };
                if (definition.Section[i].IsNa)
                {
                    if ((string)formdata["Form"][i][definition.Section[i].SectionId]["IsNa"] == string.Empty)
                    {
                        formdata["Form"][i][definition.Section[i].SectionId]["IsNa"] = false;
                    }
                    var Na = new KanCheckBox("NA");
                    Na.StyleId = "IsNa";
                    Na.IsChecked = (bool)formdata["Form"][i][definition.Section[i].SectionId]["IsNa"];
                    data.Add("IsNa", (string)formdata["Form"][i][definition.Section[i].SectionId]["IsNa"]);
                    Na.OnCheckedChange += (object s, bool IsChecked) =>
                    {

                        data[Na.StyleId] = Convert.ToString(IsChecked);
                    };
                    horizontalLayoutNaNop.Children.Add(Na);
                }

                if (definition.Section[i].IsNop)
                {
                    if ((string)formdata["Form"][i][definition.Section[i].SectionId]["IsNop"] == string.Empty)
                    {
                        formdata["Form"][i][definition.Section[i].SectionId]["IsNop"] = false;
                    }
                    var Nop = new KanCheckBox("No Problem Found");
                    Nop.StyleId = "IsNop";
                    Nop.IsChecked = (bool)formdata["Form"][i][definition.Section[i].SectionId]["IsNop"];
                    data.Add("IsNop", (string)formdata["Form"][i][definition.Section[i].SectionId]["IsNop"]);
                    Nop.OnCheckedChange += (object s, bool IsChecked) =>
                    {

                        data[Nop.StyleId] = Convert.ToString(IsChecked);
                    };
                    horizontalLayoutNaNop.Children.Add(Nop);
                }
                sectionLayout.Children.Add(horizontalLayoutNaNop);
                sectionLayout.Children.Add(new BoxView
                {
                    BackgroundColor = Color.FromHex("#ECECEC"),
                    HeightRequest = 1,
                    HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand
                });
            }


            if (definition.Section[i].subsection.Count != 0)
            {
                foreach (var sub in definition.Section[i].subsection)
                {
                    if (sub.SubSectionTitle != string.Empty)
                    {
                        var subtitle = new Label
                        {
                            Text = sub.SubSectionTitle,
                            HorizontalTextAlignment = TextAlignment.Start,
                            FontSize = 15,
                            FontAttributes = FontAttributes.Bold,
                            TextColor = Color.FromHex("#7635EB")
                        };
                        sectionLayout.Children.Add(subtitle);
                    }

                    //  (string)formdata["Form"][i][definition.Section[i].SectionId][el.Property]
                    foreach (var el in sub.elements)
                    {
                        var x = el.Type;
                        //AddElements(el, true, i, definition.Section[i].SectionId, sectionLayout, horizontalLayout);

                        int lvl = 0;
                        Dictionary<string, List<FormElement>> dt = new Dictionary<string, List<FormElement>>();
                        List<FormElement> lt = new List<FormElement>();
                        Stack<FormElement> stk = new Stack<FormElement>();

                        stk.Push(el);
                        while (stk.Count > 0)
                        {
                            var parent = stk.Pop();

                            if (parent.Elements.Count != 0)
                            {
                                AddElements(parent, true, i, definition.Section[i].SectionId, sectionLayout, horizontalLayout);
                                while (stk.Count != 0)
                                {
                                    lt.Add(stk.Pop());

                                }
                                if (lt.Count != 0)
                                {
                                    dt.Add("child" + lvl, lt);
                                    lt = new List<FormElement>();
                                    lvl++;
                                }
                                for (var j = 1; j <= parent.Elements.Count; j++)
                                {
                                    stk.Push(parent.Elements[parent.Elements.Count - j]);
                                }

                            }
                            else
                            {
                                if (stk.Count > 0)
                                {
                                    AddElements(parent, false, i, definition.Section[i].SectionId, sectionLayout, horizontalLayout);

                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    AddElements(parent, false, i, definition.Section[i].SectionId, sectionLayout, horizontalLayout);
                                    if (dt.Count > 0)
                                    {
                                        lt = dt["child" + lvl];
                                        dt.Remove("child" + lvl);
                                        for (var j = 1; j <= lt.Count; j++)
                                        {
                                            stk.Push(lt[lt.Count - j]);
                                            lvl--;
                                        }

                                    }

                                }

                            }

                        }


                        if (horizontalLayout.Children.Count != 0)
                        {
                            sectionLayout.Children.Add(horizontalLayout);
                            horizontalLayout = new StackLayout
                            {
                                Orientation = StackOrientation.Horizontal,
                                BackgroundColor = Color.White
                            };
                        }

                    }
                }
            }
            section.Children.Add(sectionLayout);
            mainLayout.Children.Add(section);

        }



        this.Content = new ScrollView
        {
            Content = mainLayout
        };
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {

    }


}
```

Here i am trying to generate the form dynamically using BuildForm.
For the first time it is generating the ui without any problem.
And when the createform is called again then the await operator is blocked.
Is there any way to get to know that MainThread has stopped executing?
Or Any way to create the child thread as a main thread so that my await operator works.

Comment: The `Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread` should not block as it just requests the UI thread action but does not wait for it to begin or even complete. Could you post the code that calls the `createForm` method? Are you sure the code blocks on the last line? Could you check with breakpoints?

Comment: can you also show how you call the createForm method

Comment: i have added my build Form Code.And CreateForm is inside the constructor FormPage().

Comment: The `Wait` here is likely the culprit: `createForm("form5")).Wait();`

Comment: @Lasse I tried removing wait but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are a little confused with the concepts here. My *Spidey Senses* tells me the deadlock is because of an `Unhandled Exception` regardless of the UI

The first thing is the `async void` looks suspicious, secondly i think there is an `Exception` happening somewhere regardless (and you need to figure that out)

```
private void Start()
{
    // invoke
    Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(SomeMethod);
}

private async void SomeMethod()
{
    try
    {
        // await method
        await SomeAsyncMethod();
    }
    catch (Exception e) // handle whatever exceptions you expect
    {
        //Handle exceptions
    }
}

private async Task SomeAsyncMethod()
{
    // in this case lets push a new page
    await Navigation.PushModalAsync(new ContentPage());
}
```

Although this is an example the take home here is, if there is a chance of not being on the `UI` thread, dispatch it on the main thread and if you are going down the road of fire-and-forget (suspicious) make sure you are handling your exceptions

Comment: MIchael thank for your reply.But no exception is coming.I applied the exception handling code.And this main thread is updating the UI.

Comment: @Ankur you need to add more code to your post, so people can better see whats going on

Comment: i have added my build Form Code.And CreateForm is inside the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tryed calling the method asynchronoulsy?

```
    private async Task ConectarWSAsync()
    {
        Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(
        async () =>
        {
            lblStatus.Text = "Getting token WS...";
            await ws.ConnectAsync();
            lblStatus.Text = "WS connected";

        }
        );
    }
```